# Notice: Array to string conversion in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I have this error which i can't seem to solve.

Here is the code

```
$this->stmt = $this->handle->prepare("SELECT * FROM tb_ph WHERE totalprofit = 0 AND status = '1' AND checks = ''");

$var = $this->stmt->fetchAll();
```

`$var` returns a multi dimensional array which i'd love to loop through so as to get their respective id and usernames. 
Now the problem is that if i do

```
foreach($var as $key => $value){
    $id = $value['id'];
    $username = $value['username'];
    $phone = $value['phone'];
}
```

i get the Notice: Array to string conversion error.

`var_dump($var)` gives

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [0] => 3
            [username] => rose
            [1] => rose
            [phone] => +2782345578952
            [2] => +2782345578952 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [0] => 4
            [username] => josh
            [1] => rose
            [phone] => +0182345578952
            [2] => +0182345578952 
        )

)
```

How do i make the loop get just id, username and phone each time for the two results returned?

Comment: Where is your code that causes the Notice? It would be better for you to show your code attempt, so that we can help you find your error, than to just expect someone to write the code for you, and you never learn how to properly debug your own code.

Comment: That's the code there. except i don't understand what you mean by code attempt

Comment: your code shown here does not have a `foreach($var ...`. You are only showing a `var_dump($var)`, and since the `$var = $this->stmt->fetchAll();` also would not create a `Notice`, then you are not showing your `foreach($var ...` code attempt.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. i've added it

Comment: thanks. how do i accept it? by up voting it right?

Comment: @ebuka - by clicking the check under the Upvote/Downvote buttons

Comment: As others have also pointed out @buka, you need to mark correct answers as correct by clicking on that small tick mark

Comment: thanks. just figured out how to mark a question as complete. can't believe i didn't see how at first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this bit very closely:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
```

It shows you that what you have is an array of arrays so what get in your foreach is another array

```
foreach($var as $arr) {
    /* here $arr is an array in calling print on it will produce the warning you have already seen but ...*/
    print $arr[$id];

}
```

Because you are printing just one element of an array here. Similarly print $arr['username']

Comment: Thank you so much. it worked but it's getting the values for just the first loop. as in my example, the array value is two but here, only one result is shown.